# Sampling: How should I sketch a signal spectrum?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

As revision, I am going through [Signals and Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0138147574), and in Section 7.1the authors are sketching representative spectra for `x(t)` and `xp(t)`as follows

[image]

However when I search for "How to draw a signal spectrum" I get results ([here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/100/misc/spectra-review.pdf) and [here](http://www.eas.uccs.edu/~mwickert/ece2610/lecture_notes/ece2610_chap3.pdf)), where signal spectra are shown like this:

[image]

For example,how should I go about sketching the the spectrum of signal x(t), where x(t) = 4cos(8000πt)?

Here are my two answers:

[image]

Which one is the correct approach? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 7.4 just concerns itself with an *example* signal, which happens to have triangular spectrum.

your $x(t)=a\cos(2\pi f t)$ signal is just that: a single cosine tone, and thus has the "shape" of two dirac impulses with integral area $\frac a2$ each.